# Cast generic within generic IQueryable<T> method

Tags: c#, generics, iqueryable

I have a generic `IQueryable` extension method used with Entity Framework:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, ...)
```

Some uses of this method take in a `T` where `T: IFoo`.

`IFoo` just has a single property:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Foo { get; }
}
```

I would like to add an if statement to the above method to check if T is `IFoo` and if so use the `Foo` property.

Something like:

```
if (typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(source.ElementType))
{
    source = source.Where(x => x.Foo == "Bar");
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because although I am checking that `T` is `IFoo`, there is no cast so I cannot access `Foo`.

I know I can have two separate methods and use a generic constraint for one but would prefer to have a single method to deal with both. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I played around and this is the potential solution I could think of.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    if (source.ElementType == typeof(IFoo))
    {
        var casted = source.Cast<IFoo>();
        var f = casted.Where(x => x.Foo == "foo");
        return f.Cast<T>();
    }

    return source;
}
```

but I still would recommend to have separate methods which you have already mentioned

Comment: Nice. I had doubts that this would translate to sql properly via Entity Framework but it works perfectly and the generated sql does not have any weird casting.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can have two separate methods and use a generic constraint for one

You can do better than a generic constraint:

```
public static IQueryable<IFoo> Search(this IQueryable<IFoo> source, ...)
```

The code will use the more-specific option when possible.

But you won't ever be able to reference a `Bar` property directly in any single method that could possibly be called with other kinds of objects. The best you could do in a single is use reflection to read the property. That's probably slower with more code than two separate methods.

Comment: Thanks. If I went ahead and had two search methods (one using IFoo as you outlined and one using the generic T I originally posted but without the if check), I could do the if in the first without any casting. Could I then call the second method from the first so the common code is executed in both scenarios or would extracting this method out into a private method called from both be better?

Comment: @KarenKatz You could absolutely call one method from the other. Either option has merits.

Comment: I tried this two method solution but unfortunately the generic version is always used. The extension methods are used on DbSet<T> where T is either IFoo or not. In both cases however, the generic overload is chosen in preference to the IFoo version.